# Getting rest_framework.exceptions.ParseError: JSON parse error - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 260: invalid start byte

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am building a rest api using django rest framework.I am making a post request through postman and passing the body as a form data as given in the below image:

[image]

The code in views.py file is:

```
def addItem(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        items = request.body
        itemStream = io.BytesIO(items)
        dataItems = JSONParser().parse(itemStream)
        serializedData = MenuSerializer(data=dataItems)
        if serializedData.is_valid():
            serializedData.save()
            responseMessage={'message':"Items added successfully"}
            return JsonResponse(responseMessage)
        json_data=JSONRenderer().render(serializedData.error)
        return HttpResponse(json_data,content_type='application/json')
```

Code of serializer.py is:

```
from dataclasses import fields
from .models import Menu
from rest_framework import serializers

class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def create(self,validated_data):
        return Menu.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Code of models.py file is:

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media")
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    discount = models.IntegerField()
    plate_size = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Do you have an idea what the raw input data looks like? If so, you can go to character number 260, which is causing your error. As a wild guess I'd say binary data from your image is messing things up.

Comment: According to your screenshot, your are sending your data as form-data, which is not JSON. It would already work better if you use `raw` and put your data here in a JSON format (as a JSON object)

Comment: Or alternatively, use the FormParser (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#formparser)

Answer (score 0):

You have selected form-data, thus data received in the request.body is not in
key value format. You can see that by printing items in the terminal.

select raw and in the drop-down select json as shown below:
[Step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6UUS.jpg)

Then write json data to be inserted in the given editor as shown below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL40A.jpg)

Then click on send.
Note: I had taken different json for